# How to use lottie js player on flutter

Tags: flutter-web, lottie

When I use the lottie player plugin from pub.dev for my flutter web project - I get an error saying:

UnimplementedError: Flutter Web does not support the blend mode: BlendMode.clear

I am trying to see if I can use the following, which works fine if I embed in google site or elsewhere.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<lottie-player src="https://assets7.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_jw5bcjov.json" background="transparent"  speed="1"   loop autoplay></lottie-player>
```

How do I put this inside a flutter web app?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit

flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit